# Can windows phone override the screen lock button?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to override the screen lock button in the windows phone app?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: No this isn't possible either, but the question still remains, why would you want to do either of these things?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one hardware button that you can interact with in your code and that's the back button.

While it's not possible to stop the user locking their phone you can have your application run under the lock screen or stop the device going into lock screen mode after inactivity while your app is running.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941090(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: What about the camera button ;)